# Image.network is blinking every time i setstate

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

ClipOval(child:Image.network("http://197.13.15.233:8787/api/v1/user/$id/picture",
fit: BoxFit.cover,
width: 40,
height: 40,
key: ValueKey(new Random().nextInt(100)),
headers: {
"authorization": "Bearer $token",
// Other headers if wanted
},
loadingBuilder:(BuildContext context, Widget child,ImageChunkEvent loadingProgress) {

```
              if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
              return ClipOval(
                child: Container(
                  width: 40,
                  height: 40,
                  child: Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null ?
                      loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded / loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes
                          : null,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
            errorBuilder: (BuildContext context, Object exception, StackTrace stackTrace) {
              return SvgPicture.asset(
                "Assets/Images/avatar.svg",
                width: 40,
                height: 40,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,

              );
            },
          ),
        )
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call `setState` the related `StatefulWidget` rebuilds. So, the networkImage is fetched again from the network.

To avoid that you can use [CachedNetworkImage](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image). It will cache your network image, no more blinking.

Comment: the blinking is when there is no image in the url . i mean the errorWidget blinking. i need a way to call the url juste one time and set in cach the image errorImage .

Comment: You will get an `errorWidget` ptroperty inside `CachedNetworkImage`. Try the package

Comment: If you're fetching the image url from api call the api inside `initState`. If you have a fixed image url you must cache the image to stop fetching imagedata everytime

Answer (score 0):

If you face the blinking issue on `CacheNetworkImage`. You can try a workaround by increasing the cache size.

```
PaintingBinding.instance.imageCache.maximumSizeBytes = 1000 << 20;
```

https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter_cached_network_image/issues/325#issuecomment-869041042